# How to get SQL data into a WPF DataGrid using powershell?

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

I am trying to add my sql query data into WPF powershell application. In `$dg` items I see my computer names which are being returned by the SQL query, but m datagrid isn't getting populated.

Here's my code

```
function Invoke-sql1
{
    param( [string]$sql,
        [System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection]$connection
    )

    $cmd = new-object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand($sql,$connection)
    $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLDataAdapter($cmd)
    $da.fill($ds) | Out-Null
    return $ds.tables[0].rows
}


[xml] $xaml = @"
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
<DataGrid 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Name="dataGrid1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="330"
    HeadersVisibility="All" 
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SystemName"
                    Binding="{Binding SystemName}" 
                    />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProcessorLoad"
                    Binding="{Binding ProcessorLoad}" 
                    />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CreatedDate"
                    Binding="{Binding CreatedDate}" 
                    />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid >
</Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )


$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString=@"
DataSource=JAPDC\SQLEXPRESS;
IntegratedSecurity=True;
Initial Catalog=TestDB;
"@
$con.open()

$sql = “​SELECT t1.SystemName, t1.ProcessorLoad, t1.CreatedDate
FROM   [TestDB].[dbo].[CPUPerformance] t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(CreatedDate) CreatedDate, SystemName
               FROM   [TestDB].[dbo].[CPUPerformance] 

              GROUP BY [TestDB].[dbo].[CPUPerformance].SystemName ) AS t2 
     ON 
         t1.SystemName = t2.SystemName
         and t1.CreatedDate = t2.CreatedDate 
ORDER  BY CreatedDate DESC ”

$dg = $Form.FindName("dataGrid1")
$dg.ItemsSource = @(Invoke-sql1 $sql $con)
$dg
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

If there is another way to do it, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function Invoke-sql1, change your return statement to this:

> return $ds.tables[0].DefaultView

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep returning .rows then you need to change the bindings to be indexed into ItemArray.

```
Binding="{Binding ItemArray[0]}"
Binding="{Binding ItemArray[1]}"
etc...
```